# manipulate the browser's default image enlarge and html elements

Tags: html, image, url, browser, cross-browser

so I'm not sure what the proper term is for this, but when I follow a link for an image asset I see that most browsers (at least the ones I've used) generate HTML markup to display the image and make it auto resize as well as give it click to enlarge functionality.

So I'm curious: is it possible to manipulate the default markup the browser generates when a URL for an image asset is resolved (i.e. http://cdn1.technology.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/firefox-logo-evolution-infographic.jpg) as well as add hooks for the click to enlarge functionality?

what I want to do is add styles to the auto-generated image tag to make it center vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do anything with it. To do something similar you will have to create a page which takes the image path in the querystring and then you will have full liberty to change it that way you want. e.g domain.com/myassetpage.php?some-image.jpg

Comment: when you follow an image link (a link to an image asset) the browser generates html markup and gives the image a "click to enlarge" functionality. follow the image link in my question and take a look at the image in the dev tools and you'll see auto-generated HTML and if you click the image it will enlarge.

Comment: so the question is: can I add styles to the markup that is auto generated and "hook" into the click to enlarge functionality the browser is using?

Comment: Ok, so you want to be to able to show image on hover and zoom when clicked similar to what eBay and other eStores do?

Comment: nope. I want to be able to manipulate what the browser creates by default. example: I have an image in assets/images/some-image.jpg and when I put mydomain.com/assets/images/some-image.jpg in the URL bar it takes me to the image, but the browser will create markup for that image and give it the ability to enlarge when clicked (most browsers do this own their own). what I want is to let the browser do what it already does, but simply style the auto-generated markup and hook into the click to enlarge functionality (i.e. like add event listeners) to add more functionality to it

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do anything with it. To do something similar you will have to create a page which take the image path in the querystring and then you will have full liberty to change it that way you want. e.g domain.com/myassetpage.php?some-image.jpg

Comment: that's a bummer. Unfortunately, that is what I was already doing. seems like such a waste of functionality.

Comment: can you change your answer to match your comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, you can use a file named "userContent.css" to declare your own default rules.

For Google Chrome [see this discussion](https://superuser.com/q/52967).

There are also add-ons that enable this behaviour. For example [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).

EDIT: the above will work in your own browsers; if you want to link your image resources on your website, you can use a separate page for that, like recommended by others or just use some lightbox-like plugin to show images in pop-ups.